# RxSwift and Moya synchronous request

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, moya

Right now i'm having a situation where i'm starting several request from separated threads, something like a Thread Pool.

I want to make that requests to be synchronous, so they will be started and ended on exactly the same thread, not the Main thread.

I tried to set the `.observeOn(CurrentThreadScheduler.instance)`, but as the response handler thread was always Main thread instead of a current.

Is it possible to specify the current thread as a handler thread for the response?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to specify the current thread as a handler thread for
>   the response?

There is a way! Take a look at `MoyaProvider` class.

```
/// Request provider class. Requests should be made through this class only.
open class MoyaProvider<Target: TargetType>: MoyaProviderType {

    /// Propagated to Alamofire as callback queue. If nil - the Alamofire default (as of their API in 2017 - the main queue) will be used.
    let callbackQueue: DispatchQueue?

    /// Initializes a provider.
    public init(..., callbackQueue: DispatchQueue? = nil, ...) {
        ...
        self.callbackQueue = callbackQueue
    }
}
```

You are allowed to provide a callback queue. Just provide the desired queue.